# linux + how to know when swapoff -a should be ended

Tags: linux, memory, swap

on my linux redhat machine I perform swapoff

in order to drop swap pages that stays in cached swap!

```
swapoff -a
```

I waiting until now one hour and swapoff still work

can we see some process or notification when swapoff should be ended ?

remark - swap size is 8G , and memory size is 60 G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to trace the swapoff process  run the command **free**

and see that after some time the total swap is decrease

in this way "total swap" should be nearly 0 when swapodd ended,

after swapoff ended perform **swapon -a**

example :

```
 free -g
                   total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:              58           35         23          0          0         24
    -/+ buffers/cache:           10         48
 Swap:              1            1           0
```

Comment: you can also check if the swap is "on" with htop